# Get html class name from React component upon mounting

Tags: dom, reactjs

Perhaps this is against the philosophy of react, but I'd like to know whether it's possible to determine the class of the component that just mounted.

For example:

```
export class HelloWorldDiv extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        // can I magically determine that the class of the component that just mounted (in this case 'hello-world')?
        // totally open to using jquery if necessary
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="hello-world">
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to achieve this goal is to add a `ref` attribute to the element you're interested in (see `render()`), and we can then access the reference via `this.refs` bv providing it the key, `myDiv`. Then using plain JS we can acquire the `class` attribute:

```
class HelloWorldDiv extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.refs.myDiv.getAttribute('class'));
    }

    render() {
        console.log('Class: ', this.constructor.name);
        return (
            <div ref="myDiv" className="hello-world">
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```